# Android: the three phone states

Tags: android

Why when a call is answered idle is not called after it finishes? I cannot figure out for the life of me how to detect the end of an incoming call. Idle works fine for missed called, but subsequent to an answered call seems like a mysterious state.

Anyone know how to detect the end of an incoming call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you answer an incoming call, the phone goes into OFF_HOOK. IDLE implies that the phone is not doing anything. When a call first comes in, the state is RINGING until you reject the call (send the phone to idle) or answer the call (send the phone to OFF_HOOK).

Comment: So OFF_HOOK means "connected"?

Comment: Well it means the phone is not ringing or idle. Safe to say connected, but I guess that could change in the future...

Comment: "Off-hook: At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK