# How to detect that the call is answered or rejected?

Tags: android, phone-call

I am making an application to call multiple numbers.
In that app

1. When **I call to 1 person and if the call is answered by the user then the loop should be stopped.**
2. But **If the call is rejected then the call should be on next number and loop should be continue.**

My problem is **I can't detect whether the call is rejected or answered.** When I had search on net some people says it is not possible to detect the call is answered or rejected.

**Is it really not possible to detect the call in android? If it is possible then how can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

There are many phone states that you can read as follow for incoming phones

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Device states ->

> if you answer an incoming call, the phone goes into OFF_HOOK. IDLE
>   implies that the phone is not doing anything. When a call first comes
>   in, the state is RINGING until you reject the call (send the phone to
>   idle) or answer the call (send the phone to OFF_HOOK).

([Android: the three phone states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277893/android-the-three-phone-states))

**Edit:** But there's no way to listen states of outgoing calls, maybe you can parse logcat logs or something else but it's impossible as far as i know, but you can try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html because there's a state named ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED maybe it can help.

Here's the issue link : [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14266)

Comment: It just check that the phone is ringing or not? but how to check that the phone is answered or not?

Comment: And here's a helpful link too [Please follow comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955024/how-to-know-if-a-call-has-been-established)

Comment: Means It not any exzact way to detact that the call is answered or not.

Comment: as far as i know No, but i recommend you to examine the link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955024/how-to-know-if-a-call-has-been-established)

Comment: @SercanOzdemir About outgoing calls, is it possible to do polling on something ? I know that the listeners way won't work, but maybe there is a different way...